# Enter event not working with react typescript

Tags: typescript-typings, react-typescript

code: `setPack(target.value)` not working on enter key. but on change works. any one help me ?

```
 <input value={pack} onKeyDown={(e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                const target = e.currentTarget as HTMLInputElement;
                if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                    setPack(target.value);//no woking
                }
            }} onChange={e => setPack(e.target.value)} />
            <button onClick={updatePack}>Update</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated with `setPack(e.currentTarget.value);` it works fine for me.